# Operation type in full integer quantization method in TensorFlowLite

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I want to apply Post-Training Quantization (Full integer) using TensorFlow model optimization package on a pre-trained model (LeNet5).
https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/post_training

```
model = Sequential()
model._name = 'LeNet5'
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(
    Conv2D(6, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='tanh', padding='same'))

model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='tanh', padding='valid'))

model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(120, activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(84, activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

and using this code I have applied Full Integer Post-Training Quantization:

```
     mnist_train, _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
     images = tf.cast(mnist_train[0], tf.float32) / 255.0
     mnist_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images)).batch(1)
     def representative_data_gen():
       for input_value in mnist_ds.take(100):
         yield [input_value]

    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
    converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen

    converter.allow_custom_ops = True
    converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.int8]
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8

    full_integer_quantization_model = converter.convert()
    open("tflite_model.tflite", "wb").write(full_integer_quantization_model)
```

It works fine in tense of accuracy but when I try to print the data type of each layer (operation, like conv, activation, bias), I see that some of operations are in int32 instead of int8.

I don't know why?

How does TFLite decide to do some ops in int32 and some in int8?

Is it possible to control this feature (is it an option) in TFLite and perform all operations as int8?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_spec
?

Bias values have 32-bits width

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any option to control this or not? Biases are always in int-32? What can we do to have Bias in int8?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).